# PHP - How to get the radio check buttons underneath without the wide distance?

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I would like to have those two radio check buttons underneath without the wide distance. Not sure what I do wrong here.. any help would be appreciated!

[image: example]

```
        <div class="row ms-3 me-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <section class="admin admin-simple-sm p-3 card-shadow">                
            <form method="POST" style="text-align: left;" action="{{url('/homepreference/' . auth()->user()->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                @csrf
                <span class="h6"> @lang('messages.new.homepreference') : </span>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline ms-4">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="homepage1">
                    <input class="form-check-input" 
                        @if (auth()->user()->homepage == '0')
                        checked="checked" 
                        @endif
                        type="radio" name="homepage" id="homepage1" value="0"> <span class="h6"> @lang('messages.new.viewallposts') </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="homepage2">
                    <input class="form-check-input" 
                        @if (auth()->user()->homepage == '1')
                        checked="checked" 
                        @endif
                        type="radio" name="homepage" id="homepage2" value="1">
                    <span class="h6">@lang('messages.new.viewfollowingposts') </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">@lang('messages.save')</button>
            </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="text-align: left;"` to the `form`

like this:

`<form method="POST" style="text-align: left;" action="{{url('/homepreference/' . auth()->user()->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive tried it, now its all to the left, but would like it in the middle, but just the radio checks underneath, and the upper radio check is somehow still a little to the right side. Ive added an updated screenshot above.

Comment: Oh I think i know the issue. You have the `<input>` inside the `<label>` tag.  move the `<label class="form-check-label" for="homepage1">` to right before the `<span class="h6">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer John! The problem sadly still exist, just tried your solution, it didn't do anything at all, no changes. If you know any other solution I would appreciate your next answer.

Comment: I believe this might be a CSS issue. Can you post your CSS code?

Comment: Thanks John! I will check for that, I need to find it first, there are so many, the whole site is not my own script, I am still checking each script. I bought it on codecanyon, but he wants more money to do script changes and stuff, and I was like nope... lol So give me a few and I will check for the css file, might take a while sorry